# How to programmatically change settings for WMI instead of using wmimgmt.msc snappin?

Tags: c#, security, vbscript, wmi

Normally you go this way:

- start -> run
- enter wmimgmt.msc and press enter
- riht click on "WMI Control" node ->
  properties
- on security tab click button security
- add new user
- for user you just add allow "Remote
  enable"

How can this be done programmatically(C# or vbs) ?
I searched the web and found sometning about doing it by using WMIC, but I don't understand how to do it. 
Here are the links if they helps you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you describe the result that you would like to achieve, ultimately?

Comment: can you check if the solution works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't explain exactly how to do this, but since you are doing something that involves some good understanding of windows, programming and administering I will simply give you a link to the source code that you can adapt into your project to manage the WMI security:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WmiSecurity.aspx

Basically what you should note is the following paragraph:

So at this point, some examples should suffice to illustrate the use of the utility. Suppose you wanted to add the domain HelpDesk group to the CIMV2 and subsequent namespaces on the S223001 computer. Further, suppose this group should have the ability to remotely connect and read WMI objects. To do this:

**WmiSecurity /C=S223001 /A /N=Root\CimV2 /M=MyDomain\HelpDesk:REMOTEACCESS /R**

Hope that it can help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do with WMI. WMI API for .net is the one you need. Here are few examples and links that may be useful to achieve your objectives.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394572

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#obtaining_data_from_WMI

WMI made it easy example: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/

[Change users parental control settings using WMI in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711277/change-users-parental-control-settings-using-wmi-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx