# Block websites with Windows 10 parental control APIs

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

I have gone through parental control API documentation on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), posted a general question about using parental controls APIs on Windows 10 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208138/how-to-use-windows-10-parental-control-apis) on Stack Overflow. But have not received a satisfactory answer, and haven't been able to locate any helpful samples in the documentation.
Right now, I have managed to go as far as this tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711277/change-users-parental-control-settings-using-wmi-in-c-sharp).

I decided to narrow down the question to this,

Is there a way to block access to specific websites using these APIs on Windows 10?

Comment: I am using WMI code creator tool, to try out parental control APIs and have attached a screenshot of two popup messages which come up when I try to "remove users" to try a remove a previously added useraccount by its SID through the WpcSystemSettings class. I have attached a link to the screenshot here, which suggests that you HAVE to go the "family safety website" to make this change. Why does this happen?  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj7cu8wlywfar2o/parentalcontrol-cannot-be-changed.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

It looks like whitelist and blacklist can be configured via WMI.

Check the `WpcURLOverride` object and its `URL` and `Allowed` properties.

More information on MSDN: [Parental Controls WMI Provider Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I had checked this section, but I haven't really understood how exactly I can use this information, can you perhaps link me to a code sample I can refer to?